# CakePHP: How to require admin role for a specific page?

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

We are using the Auth component. We are currently able to prevent non-logged in users from visiting our "admin" page (adminhome.ctp). But we can't figure out how to make `isAuthorized()` prevent non-admins from visiting the page also.

Inside the AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'login', 'logout', 'display');
    $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller'); 
    //$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
}

public function isAuthorized($user_id) {
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $user = $this->User->findById($this->Auth->user());
    if ( $user['User']['role'] === 'admin') {
        $this->Session->setFlash('isAuthorized');
        return true;
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash('!isAuthorized');
    return false;
}
```

Here the beforeFilter() in PagesController:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->deny('adminhome');
}
```

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your way it doesn't work because you should use Auth->deny() to restrict access to methods, and adminhome is not a method in the PagesController. Try this:

```
# in app/controller/PagesController.php
public function display() {
  $page = empty($this->request->params['pass'][0]) ? null : $this->request->params['pass'][0];
  if($page == 'adminhome' || $this->User->isAuthorized()) {
    $this->render($page);
  } else {
    # redirect the user somewhere else
  }
}
```

I hope this  helps

Comment: We are using admin routing. It's working perfectly on all the controllers, but it doesn't seem to apply to pages because as you pointed out, 'adminhome' isn't a method. I'll try your version, but I'm confused how it will solve my specific problem which involves a particular page rendered by the PagesController. In other words `$this->Auth->deny()` can't reference a specific page, can it?

Comment: I guess I'm confused by your answer because the first block (using admin prefixes as we would like) doesn't seem to reference pages at all.

Comment: Nevermind the first part of the answer if you are using admin routing already. And yeah, $this->Auth->deny() probably can't reference specific pages, which is why you have to use the display() and isAuthorized() methods in your case like I pointed out in the second part.

Comment: I'll actually edit that out, since it doesn't relate to your question.

Comment: I see. Should that display() function relapse the default function that appears in that file out of the box? I've never see a function defined with a string parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I made a really big mess of the answer, I was kind of going by memory. I edited it now with something I actually use. You have to check which page is being requested first, so the parameter on the display() action was way off.

Comment: Also I recommend reading [this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/joelstein/2007/05/02/taking-advantage-of-the-pages-controller). Pages are a bit annoying to work with in my experience.

Comment: Should the operator be `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: @devJunk I'm having a similar issue. What specifically does the "pass" portion of the array represent? $this->request->params['pass'][0] ?

Comment: Late answer, but it represent parameters passed through the URL:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passed-arguments

Answer (score 2):

I have just used Aryan answer however I have made some minor changes which could be helpful for others:

```
if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role') != 'admin')
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('You are not authorized to visit this page');
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have role field in user table. In particular action add this line

```
if($this->Session->read('Auht.User.role') != 'admin') {
      ...............................
}
```

If you want only admin can see every actions in some controller like admincontroller

you can add this code in that controller in beforeRender action

```
if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role') != 'admin')
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(You are not authorized to visit this page,'flash',array('alert'=>'info'));
                $this->redirect('/');
            }
```